# Find the relative angle of eyes ( left, right, up, down, straight )

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, tracking

I have used [STASM](http://www.milbo.users.sonic.net/stasm/) and found the eye co-ordinates in a live video stream. Now my intention is to find the relative angle of eyes to find whether the eye is focussing towards left,right,up, down, or straight.

Can some one point me to the right links or sources to find this?

**Input :** Frames from the web camera

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem you're trying to solve is gaze estimation. Take a look at the research and code from ITU gaze group : http://www.gazegroup.org/